# Test Driven Development c++ : How do I add an object to a vector in terms of a song to a playlist and test it

Tags: c++, vector, playlist

```
void PlayListTester::testAddSong(){
   cout << "- addSong()... " << flush;
   PlayList pList("addSongTest.txt");
   Song s1("Badge", "Cream", 1969);
   Song s2("Godzilla", "Blue Oyster Cult", 1977);
   Song s3("Behind Blue Eyes", "The Who", 1971);
   pList.addSong(s1);
   vector<Song> searchResult = pList.searchByArtist("Cream");
   assert( searchResult.size() == 1 );
   assert( searchResult[0].getTitle() == "Badge" );
   assert( searchResult[0].getYear() == 1969 );
   assert( searchResult[0].getArtist() == "Cream" );
   cout << " 0 " << flush;
```

}
This is the tester method that I have made for adding Song objects to a PlayList vector, but my problem is that it doesn't throw an error, but instead the code terminates at the first assert. I am just confused as to whether it is my test that is faulty or whether it is my method itself.

```
vector<Song> PlayList::addSong(const Song& newSong){
      vector<Song> v;
      v.push_back(newSong);
      return v;
```

This is the method that I used. It seems maybe too simple, but in theory as far as I can see it should work.

```
PlayList::PlayList(const string& fileName) {
  // open a stream to the playlist file
  ifstream fin( fileName.c_str() );
  assert( fin.is_open() );

  // read each song and append it to mySongs
  Song s;
  string separator;
  while (true) {
      s.readFrom(fin);
      if ( !fin ) { break; }
      getline(fin, separator);
      mySongs.push_back(s);
  }

  // close the stream
  fin.close();
```

}
Here is my PlayList constructor if that helps any. The code fails at the size assert.

Comment: You're already pushing back an object of `Song` into the vector. Have you tried running the code? Also, you're second line will not execute `addSong()`, you have it in quotation marks. Try run the code and see if you get the results you expect.

Comment: Which assert is failing? If you don't capture the result of your `addSong` method, did it even happen?

Comment: The assert for the size is failing, and yes I have run the code. I am aware the addSong() is in quotations as that is just the console displaying its run through the test methods.

Comment: By capture do you mean assigning it to something?

Comment: If you provided a [mcve] perhaps we could say something like "you need to modify the vector PlayList contains instead of having a function with no side effects", but there's not enough code for that.

Comment: you're creating a vector, adding it and returning it, but you don't store the vector anywhere...

Comment: I am storing it into the pList vector as far as I can see

Comment: Look again. `vector<Song> v;` declares a local variable. Whatever you do to that variable is lost as soon as that function ends, unless you assign the return value to something.

Comment: Okay then let me ask the question how would I go about assigning it to something? I am returning what I need to, but now how do I assign that to something to store it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside the `Playlist::addSong()` method you are just making a vector object that contains Song objects, push_back a song to it. In that moment, that vector only has one element, that song you just pushed. You return it, but you don't do anything with it in the method you called the function from, so the vector is just destroyed and its memory deallocated. Assuming that the Playlist class has a private vector that holds the songs, what you should do in that method is to push_back the song on that vector. Not something you just created there.

I think mySongs is the vector you ultimately want to contain the song, so it would go something along the lines of:

```
void PlayList::addSong(const Song& newSong) {
 this->mySongs.push_back(newSong);
}
```

Comment: So I believe the way you put the method worked because it gets past my first assertion, but what would my test assertions after size look like if that is the case? Edit: I figured the tests out on my own, thank you!

Comment: Also be wary of the fact that you are not doing any checks on what you are adding to the playlist. Normally you would check for some things, like the strings not to be empty or a valid year. The addSong method would then return different numbers for different errors. For example, if the year didn't check out, make the method return a 1. If the name is empty, return 2. After the checks are done, push the song and return 0 for success. And when you call this function, checking to see if it returned 0 or something else is very handy when debugging.